# Loop validation and output problems

Tags: java, loops

So I have everything working except that once I enter the input required I get input like this:

```
1   5.0
2   6.0
3   7.0
4   8.0
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong as it seems its not increasing in the right increments based on the growthRate that I input which was 50. Also can't get the organism number to increase according to the following day. Any suggestions?

```
//Purpose of program to predict population of organisms

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Population {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double growthRate = -1;
        int population = 0;
        int days = -1;
        double popResult = 0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nEnter the starting number of organisms:");
        population = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (population < 2) {
            System.out.println("\nError!! Please re-enter number of organisms.");
            population = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("\nEnter rate of growth as percentage:");
        growthRate = keyboard.nextInt() / 100;

        while (growthRate < 0) {
            System.out.println("\nError!! Growth rate must be a positive number. Please re-enter.");
            growthRate = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("\nEnter number of days organisms will grow:");
        days = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (days < 0) {
            System.out.println("\nError!! Number of days cannot be less than 1. Please re-enter.");
            days = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Days" + "\t" + "Organisms");
        System.out.println("------------------");

        popResult = population;
        growthRate = growthRate / 100;

        for (int numberOfDays = 1; numberOfDays < days; numberOfDays++) {
            System.out.println(numberOfDays + "\t" + popResult);
            popResult = (popResult * growthRate) + popResult;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `keyboard.nextInt()/100` is integer division.  The result will always be an integer.  If you want a `double` result, cast one of the operands to a `double`.

Comment: Would that fix the problem I am having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking input for growthRate as Integer format in line

growthRate=keyboard.nextInt()/100;

If it is less than 0 then you take input without dividing by 100 as

growthRate=keyboard.nextInt();

and finally you are again dividing growthRate as
growthRate=growthRate/100;

So you have to take input outside the while loop only as
growthRate=keyboard.nextInt();

Modified code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Population
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double growthRate=-1;
        int population=0;
        int days=-1;
        double popResult=0;

        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nEnter the starting number of organisms:");
        population=keyboard.nextInt();

        while(population<2)
        {
            System.out.println("\nError!! Please re-enter number of organisms.");
            population=keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("\nEnter rate of growth as percentage:");
        growthRate=keyboard.nextInt();

        while(growthRate<0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nError!! Growth rate must be a positive number. Please re-enter.");
            growthRate=keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("\nEnter number of days organisms will grow:");
        days=keyboard.nextInt();

        while(days<0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nError!! Number of days cannot be less than 1. Please re-enter.");
            days=keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Days" + "\t" +  "Organisms");
        System.out.println("------------------");

        popResult=population;
        growthRate=growthRate/100;

        for(int numberOfDays=1; numberOfDays<days; numberOfDays++)
        {
            System.out.println(numberOfDays + "\t" + popResult);
            popResult=(popResult * growthRate) + popResult;

        }}}
```

Comment: Thank you I must've overlooked that. The problem I'm running into now is that say I enter 5 for the number of days well it only outputs 4 days?

Comment: Use this in for loop int numberOfDays=1; numberOfDays<=days; numberOfDays++

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Should I set numberOfDays=0?

Comment: Change the condition in for loop in which you are printing.Use   for(int numberOfDays=1; numberOfDays<=days; numberOfDays++)

Comment: Roger, thank you for your help. It is much appreciated.